# Server 18.04 install on NVMe?

Tags: server, 18.04, nvme

I just got an NVMe in my machine that I using as a server, but I can't seem to get 18.04 installed. It crashes during the installation, as 17.10.4 does as well, that later crashes when it is trying to write grub.
18.04 just crashes more quickly with less info.

Comment: Is your BIOS updated to the latest version? Are you booting via UEFI? Is the partition layout you're using, correct for UEFI boot? 16.04 and 18.04 both should install just fine on NVMe as long as the prerequisite conditions are met.

Comment: It is, it seems like the NVMe I got is broken, returning it today.